# Ocean shader on a custom gltf model

Tags: three.js, shader, gltf

I have a 3D model and i want to apply ocean shader to it.
I want to combine "shaders / ocean" and "loader / gltf" example scenes.
I want to see ocean shader on my custom 3D model, I am so sorry because of my small knowlage.

```
            const waterMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xff0000});

                const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( 'models/gltf/DamagedHelmet/glTF/' );
                loader.load( 'DamagedHelmet.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

                    gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {

                        if ( child.isMesh ) {

                        waterGeo = child;

                        }

                    } );

                    water = new Water(
                        waterGeo,
                        {
                            textureWidth: 512,
                            textureHeight: 512,
                            waterNormals: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'textures/waternormals.jpg', function ( texture ) {

                                texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

                            } ),
                            sunDirection: new THREE.Vector3(),
                            sunColor: 0xffffff,
                            waterColor: 0x001e0f,
                            distortionScale: 3.7,
                            fog: scene.fog !== undefined
                        }
                    );  

                    water.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;

                    scene.add( water );
```

Answer (score 0):

you must change water = new Water(waterGeo,{the some code you have})
to new Water(waterGeo.geometry,{the some code you have})